# Creating a new project from a project skeleton using git

Tags: git

In order to get a new django project up and running faster, I'd like to maintain a separate "project skeleton" on which I base all my new projects. It would be great if, as I improved the skeleton, I could bring those improvements into my active projects. How can I accomplish this with git?

So, maybe in my remote git repository machine I would have 1 repo for each project and one for the skeleton?

- proj-A-repo
- proj-B-repo
- skeleton-repo

If I want to create a new proj-C locally based on the skeleton, then push my local changes up to the remote server in a new repo called proj-C-repo, how might I do this?

I've read through quite a bit of git documentation, but I'm confused about how to go about this. Do I need to clone the skeleton, or create an empty repo and then track a remote branch, or something else?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is exactly what git (or any DVCS) is good at. Give the skeleton its own repo; to create a new project you'd typically `clone` the skeleton onto your workstation, work away, then `push` to a different location (e.g. myserver:repo-C). If you later improve the skeleton and push changes to it, you can work them into an existing project with `git pull myserver:skeleton` and then merging.

Comment: To expand on this, I also found this answer about adding and renaming git remotes helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221840/error-remote-origin-already-exists-on-git-push-to-new-repository

Comment: Yea, the key is renaming the hooks after the clone. You can also clone and rename remotes directly on the "central" server before the clone/pull to your workstation. You should definitely clone/push to an off-workstation repo before you get more than a couple hours into the new project so others can see what you're up to, and you have a ref to revert to.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

Create a Git repo that is your skeleton and add the stuff that's in A and B repo to your .gitignore.
Then init new git repositories in A and B location and push to there.

That way you end up with:

```
skeleton
 +---> .git
 +---> project A
     +-----> .git
 +---> project B
     +-----> .git
```

I just tried this and it worked having a git repo inside a git repo, as long as you add the subrepo to the .gitignore..

Comment: It strikes me as a little odd to have projects "contained" in the skeleton.

Comment: I think the general idea was to have the skeleton be it's own project that is re-useable with other projects. So having them share parts of their history is not really good since you'd have to cherry-pick all changes back to the skeleton.. But cherry-picking would also work

Comment: Cool nested git repo idea. May be quite useful for other applications.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a good example of project skeleton with this [sbt console template](http://github.com/mgutz/sbt-console-template)

If you clone it and [launch sbt](http://code.google.com/p/simple-build-tool/wiki/Setup), you will get a fully functional **[Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/)** project:

- which can be compiled, executed, tested and even eclipsified (to be imported as an eclipse project)!.
- which can be stored in a Git repo of its own, with `.gitignore` already configured.