# GitHub "fatal: remote origin already exists"

Tags: git, github

I am trying to follow along [Michael Hartl's Rails tutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/) but I've run across an error.

I signed up at GitHub, issued a new SSH key, and created a new repository. But when I enter the next line into the terminal, I get the following error:

```
Parkers-MacBook-Pro:.ssh ppreyer$ git remote add origin git@github.com:ppreyer/first_app.git
fatal: remote origin already exists.
```

Just wondered if anybody else has run across this problem?

Comment: If you yet created the git repository, look at the `.git/config` file to see if origin isn't yet declared.

Comment: I was facing the same problem and used the command "git remote rm origin" then use the command git remote add origin URL.

Comment: @AkhzarNazir please add this as an answer. It worked for me.

Comment: I removed my 2 factor authentication and it worked for me.

Answer (score 1220, accepted):

**Short version:**

You should just update the existing remote:

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:ppreyer/first_app.git
```

**Long version:**

As the error message indicates, there is already a remote configured with the same name. So you can either add the new remote with a different name or update the existing one if you don't need it.

To add a new remote, called for example `github` instead of `origin` (which obviously already exists in your system), do the following:

```
git remote add github git@github.com:ppreyer/first_app.git
```

Remember though, everywhere in the tutorial you see *"origin"* you should replace it with *"github"*. For example `$ git push origin master` should now be `$ git push github master`.

However, if you want to see what that already existing `origin` remote is, you can do a `$ git remote -v`. If you think this is there by some error, you can update it like so:

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:ppreyer/first_app.git
```

Comment: Why would origin exist in his new repository? He should fix the problem (ensuring for example origin is the correct alias to github) instead of creating a new alias he would have to remind.

Comment: Ok that worked but then when I go to the next step and enter git push -u origin master into the terminal I get the following error: ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly  What does that mean?

Comment: What does `git remote -v` outputs? Also, can you try `git push origin master`?

Comment: `git remote rm origin` did not quite work. It produced *error: Could not remove config section 'remote.origin'*

Comment: @zespri: use `git remote set-url --add origin git@github.com/username/repo.git`

Comment: @DenysSéguret he could have added e.g. a https with basic auth, but then decided to go through the SSH path, this would effectively create an "origin" even with failed auth.

Answer (score 491):

This worked:

```
git remote rm origin
git remote add origin git@github.com:username/myapp.git
```

Comment: can anyone explain this? git remote rm origin

Comment: @KickButtowski rm is in reference to the remove command used in *nix. So this command tells git to "remove" the remote server details named "origin".

Comment: No need to do this in 2 steps when you can do it in 1. See my answer.

Answer (score 60):

First do a:

```
git remote rm origin
```

then

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/your_user/your_app.git
```

and voila! Worked for me!

Comment: Why to remove origin ? Is there any way we can add anything instead of origin?

Comment: git remote rename [current name] [new name]

Answer (score 41):

You can see what remote repositories you are configured to connect to via

```
git remote -v
```

That will return a list in this format:

```
origin  git@github.com:github/git-reference.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:github/git-reference.git (push)
```

That might help you figure out what the original 'origin' pointed to.

If you want to keep the remote connection that you see with the -v, but still want to follow the Rails tutorial without having to remember 'github' (or some other name) for your tutorial's repo, you can rename your *other* repository with the command:

```
git remote rename [current name] [new name]
```

as in:

```
git remote rename origin oldrepo
```

You should then be able to resume your tutorial.

Answer (score 37):

For those of you running into the ever so common error "fatal: remote origin already exists.", or when trying to remove origin and you get "error: could not remove config section remote.origin", what you need to do is to set the origin manually.

Window's POSH~Git for Windows PowerShell (and GitHub for Windows' app) has a problem with this.

I ran into this, like I do so often, again when setting up my octopress.  So, here's how I got it working.

First, check your remotes:

```
C:\gd\code\octopress [source +2 ~3 -0 !]> git remote -v
octopress       https://github.com/imathis/octopress.git (fetch)
octopress       https://github.com/imathis/octopress.git (push)
origin
```

You'll first note that my origin has no url.  Any attempt to remove it, rename it, etc all fails.

So, change the url manually:

```
git remote set-url --add origin https://github.com/eduncan911/eduncan911.github.io.git
```

Then you can confirm it worked by running `git remote -v` again:

```
C:\gd\code\octopress [source +2 ~3 -0 !]> git remote -v
octopress       https://github.com/imathis/octopress.git (fetch)
octopress       https://github.com/imathis/octopress.git (push)
origin  https://github.com/eduncan911/eduncan911.github.io.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/eduncan911/eduncan911.github.io.git (push)
```

This has fixed dozens of git repos I've had issues with, GitHub, BitBucket GitLab, etc.

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks @eduncan911. The github instructions state to do a "git init" to create a new repository on the command line. This creates an origin remote with no URL using that PS interface.

Comment: Ah yah, that's another gotcha and why you have to do this. +1  Maybe we should report this to POSH Git on github.

Comment: How do i find the url when using gitlab?

Comment: @MennoGouw I think that's an off-topic question; but, usually it's on the Repo's dashboard/home.  It's also in the settings for the project as well.

Answer (score 33):

In the special case that you are creating a new repository starting from an old repository that you used as template (Don't do this if this is not your case). Completely erase the git files of the old repository so you can start a new one:

```
rm -rf .git
```

And then restart a new git repository as usual:

```
git init
git add whatever.wvr ("git add --all" if you want to add all files)
git commit -m "first commit"
git remote add origin git@github.com:ppreyer/first_app.git
git push -u origin master
```

Answer (score 24):

update the origin if it exist already using this command

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/SriramUmapathy/ReduxLearning.git
```

Comment: Thank-you. You saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 15):

If you need to check which remote repos you have connected with your local repos, theres a cmd:

```
git remote -v
```

Now if you want to remove the remote repo (say, origin) then what you can do is:

```
git remote rm origin
```

Comment: This looks more like a comment than an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: @NathanTuggy No, it's a complete answer, and in my humble opinion, more direct than the most popular one on this thread.

Comment: @daOnlyBG: I'm not sure what the answer looked like when I saw it, since that was before comments locked in grace periods (and it may therefore have been silently edited). But now, it's reasonably complete, I agree.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Woah, didn't know there were silent edits once upon a time. That explains.

Answer (score 13):

I am facing issue in **Bitbucket** while push the code in remote

Follow below steps:

**Step-1:** Update the existing remote

```
git remote set-url origin https://pratik@bitbucket.org/pratik/demoapp.git
```

**Step-2:** You can use this command to force changes to the server with the local repository. Remote repo code will be replaced with your local repo code.

```
git push -f origin master
```

`-f` Usually, the command refuses to update a remote ref that is not an ancestor of the local ref used to overwrite it.

Answer (score 9):

That error message indicates that you already have a remote in your git directory.
If you are satisfied with that remote, your can push your code. If not or if you can't push just:

```
git remote remove origin
git remote add origin git@github.com:ppreyer/first_app.git
```

Voilà !

Answer (score 9):

The concept of `remote` is simply the URL of your remote repository.

The `origin` is an *alias* pointing to that URL. So instead of writing the whole URL every single time we want to push something to our repository, we just use this alias and run:

`git push -u origin master`

Telling to git to `push` our code from our *local **master** branch* to the *remote **origin** repository*.

Whenever we *clone a repository*, **git** creates this alias for us by default. Also whenever we create a *new repository*, we just create it our self.

Whatever the case it is, we can always change this name to anything we like, running this:

```
git remote rename [current-name] [new-name]
```

Since it is stored on the client side of the **git** application (on our machine) changing it will not affect anything in our development process, neither at our remote repository. Remember, it is only a *name* pointing to an *address*.

The only thing that changes here by renaming the alias, is that we have to declare this **new name** every time we push something to our repository.

`git push -u my-remote-alias master`

Obviously a single name can not point to two different addresses. That's why you get this error message. There is already an alias named `origin` at your local machine. To see how many aliases you have and what are they, you can initiate this command:

```
git remote -v
```

This will show you all the aliases you have plus the corresponding URLs.

You can remove them as well if you like running this:

```
git remote rm my-remote-alias
```

#### So in brief:

- find out what do you have already,
- remove or rename them,
- add your new aliases.

Happy coding.

Comment: great explanation in details! exactly what I was looking for. underrated answer imo

Answer (score 6):

if you already add project for another storage, like you upload to github and then you upload to bitbucket then it shows this type of Error.

How to remove Error: delete git-hub file in your project and then repeat the following steps...

```
git init       
git remote add origin git@bitbucket.org:Yourname/firstdemotry.git  
git add -A  
git commit -m 'Message'  
git push -u origin master
```

Answer (score 6):

- `$ git remote add origin git@gitlab.com:abc/backend/abc.git`

  In this command origin is not part of command it is just name of your remote repository. You can use any name you want.

  - **First You can check that what it contains using below command**

  `$ git remote -v`

  It will gives you result like this

  `origin  git@gitlab.com:abc/backend/abc.git (fetch)
  origin  git@gitlab.com:abc/backend/abc.git (push)
  origin1 git@gitlab.com:abc/backend/abc.git (fetch)
  origin1 git@gitlab.com:abc/backend/abc.git (push)`

  if it contains your remote repository path then you can directly push to that without adding origin again

  - **If it is not contaning your remote repository path**

  Then you can add new origin with different name and use that to push like
  `$ git remote add origin101 git@gitlab.com:abc/backend/abc.git`

  Or you can rename existing origin name add your origin

  `git remote rename origin destination`

  fire below command again

  `$ git remote -v`

  `destination     git@gitlab.com:abc/backend/abc.git (fetch)
  destination     git@gitlab.com:abc/backend/abc.git (push)`

  It will change your existing repos name so you can use that origin name

  Or you can just remove your existing origin and add your origin

  `git remote rm destination`

Answer (score 5):

It can also happen if you run the command in directory without git initialized. If that's the case run first:

```
git init
```

Answer (score 5):

facing same error while add repository to git hun using git bash on windows

```
 git remote add origin https://github.com/axaysushir/netflix_page_clone.git
```

fatal: remote origin already exists.

```
fatal: remote origin already exists.

 ! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
```

error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/axaysushir/meditation_app_using_js.git'

> Update repository by following command

```
$ git remote set-url origin https://github.com/axaysushir/netflix_page_clone.git
```

> then add repository using git remote add github instead git remote add origin

```
$ git remote add github https://github.com/axaysushir/netflix_page_clone.git
```

> And then write following command instead of git push origin master this will upload your repository to github

```
$ git push github master
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this

- cd existing_repo
- git remote rename origin old-origin

Comment: Bro thanks, this is the only thing that worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

for using git you have to be

> root

if not then use sudo

> for removing origin :
>
> git remote remove origin

for adding origin :

git remote add origin http://giturl

Answer (score 3):

If you are getting an error like "error: remote origin already exists."
then please try following command **to remove already existing remote origin**

```
git remote remove origin
```

then use your commmand

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:ppreyer/first_app.git
```

**If you don't want to delete existing remote record then update it**

```
git remote set-url <REMOTE-NAME> <NEW-URL>
```

then use your commmand

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:ppreyer/first_app.git
```

**If you want to rename your existing project use following command**

```
git remote rename <old-name> <new-name>
```

if you want to rename your origin remote to backup. You'd simply run:

```
git remote rename origin backup
```

Thank you!!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Please replace "add" in "git remote add origin git@github.com" with "set-url" in git remote set-url origin git@github.com

Answer (score 0):

First check To see how many aliases you have and what are they, you can initiate this command
git remote -v

Then see in which repository you are in
then try
git remote set-url --add [Then your repositpory link]
git push -u origin master

Answer (score 0):

On bash at least, we can force the return value of the exit code of the command to be 0

You can remove the old remote and add it again

```
git remote remove $1 || true
git remote add $1 $2
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to do via GUI do the following:

1. Ensure "hidden files" are visible in your project folder
2. Go to .git directory
3. Edit the url file in the config.txt file and save the file!

Answer (score 0):

Do not pay attention to the error and write this:

git push -u origin main

Answer (score 0):

```
git remote set-url origin https://username:PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN@github.com:ppreyer/first_app.git
git push -u origin main
```

You can generate personal accesss token using following steps on github:

- Goto to settings
- Click on Developer settings
- Click on Generate new token
- Generate your personal access token and paste it on the above command. :)

Answer (score 0):

Very simple solution for this error :- error: remote origin already exists.
Might be you hit this command

> git remote add origin https://github.com/rahulgupta020/cardorganizer.git

To change this command add to set-url

> git remote set-url origin https://github.com/rahulgupta020/cardorganizer.git

Answer (score -2):

try this command it works for me.

rm -rf .git/

Comment: This will kill your repo. **Do not do it**.