# Google App Engine "remote origin already exists"

Tags: git, google-app-engine, repository

I've been hitting my head on the wall trying to figure out how to configure my repository on Google App Engine. I've been following these instructions https://developers.google.com/cloud/devtools/repo/cloud-repositories#setting_up_the_repository_as_a_git_remote but when I get to the step

```
gcloud init <my-app-id>
```

I get the error:

```
fatal: remote origin already exists
```

For the life of me, I cannot figure out when I could have done such a thing. Any advice on what I can to undo the problem would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running the command gcloud init  in other folders? Does it give you the same error everywhere?

Comment: Yes, and yes. No luck.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact problem using git from a Windows Github installation. This Stackoverflow answer solved my problem, and suggested an explaination: [Github "fatal: remote origin already exists"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10904339/github-fatal-remote-origin-already-exists#answer-22826225)