# origin is not assigned to any repository

Tags: git

I was trying to add a remote repository and assign it to `origin` but got this error:
`fatal: remote origin already exists.`
then I checked all the remote repositories by `remote -v` and here is the result:

```
android https://github.com/hooman-y/cw-omnibus.git (fetch)
android https://github.com/hooman-y/cw-omnibus.git (push)
origin
upstream        https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus.git (fetch)
upstream        https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus.git (push)
```

It seems `origin` is not assigned to any repository and yet it can't be assigned, renamed or deleted. I know this problem is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10904339/github-fatal-remote-origin-already-exists) but none of the methods works for me.

EDITED:
here is my `/.git/config` content:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
    hideDotFiles = dotGitOnly
[branch "master"]
[remote "android"]
    url = https://github.com/hooman-y/cw-omnibus.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/android/*
[remote "upstream"]
    url = https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/upstream/*
```

Comment: Do you mean that `git remote set-url origin <url-here>` does not work?  What error(s) if any occur?  What are the contents of `.git/config`?

Comment: `git remote add github <url>` and got that error

Comment: Curious; those contents indicate you should have two `remote`s, `android` and `upstream`, and no `origin`.  Perhaps a broken version of git?

Comment: Do you have something named `origin` in your `.git/refs/remotes/` folder? Does `git branch -r` show you anything of `origin`?

Comment: @Aaron Please don't post your .git/config as a comment. Edit your question instead

Comment: @Kissaki no, dont have that folder and didn't show anything

Comment: At this point I’d just clone the repository again. If you don’t want to lose history from your current clone, you can add that one as a remote as well and pull any changes you have there.

Comment: @Kissaki yep I guess that's the only option I have. Thanks