# Unable to add project to Github from android studio

Tags: android, github, android-studio

I am getting the error as

" Can't add remote
            fatal: remote origin already exists.
            during executing git remote add origin https://github.com/Aditya547/HelloWorld12.git"

Although it is for the first time with that name , repo is being created but project is not getting into it

Answer (score 0):

You can't add origin since its already there but you can update it. Instead of git remote add command, you can run from your git bash/command line:

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:Aditya547/HelloWorld12.git
```

find more in this link: [More info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10904339/github-fatal-remote-origin-already-exists)