# Android Studio Share Project on GitHub Error

Tags: android, github, android-studio

Every time I try to click Share Project on GitHub on Android Studio 1.01 I get this error. I would like it so that I won't have to go to the terminal and fix it with commands everytime I want to put a project onto GitHub.

> Can't add remote
>   fatal: remote origin already exists.

I never made a repository with the same name. What I get is an empty repository on GitHub.
Funny thing is it was working fine before I installed the new stable version of Android Studio.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Github "fatal: remote origin already exists"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10904339/github-fatal-remote-origin-already-exists). This was the first search result on google and I just copied your error. Please search before asking a question.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I actually searched already. This occurs when I press the "Share on Github" in Android Studio, it's not something that occurs in the terminal. It's a rather strange error that has been happening on this computer but not my other.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to figure it out, if you want to avoid having to manually add your origin everytime you want to share. Basically make sure the correct git.exe is installed. I had to install a new version of git to get it working again. Thanks guys.