# Cannot push in git, Repository not found error

Tags: git, github

I just created a new github account and then installed GitHub on my Windows 7.

I tried to use my comand line but when I type `git` says

> git is not recognized as an internal or external command.

I checked the PATH and it is `C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_c2ba306e536fdf878271f7fe636a147ff3I` can find a `cmd` folder in that path.

But, anyway, to avoid the hash I started using Git Shell. When I try to do `git push` I get

```
Warning: Permanently added 'github.com,192.30.252.128' (RSA) to the list of know
n hosts.
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I [authenticated](https://help.github.com/desktop/guides/getting-started/authenticating-to-github/) to gitHub. I also [generated](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/) SSH keys but when I tried to add it to the SSH keys in my account in gitHub.com I got `Key is already in use`.

So, I have no clue what is going on. I did my best, please help me.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a git remote?  If not, learn how to [here](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-remote/).

Comment: @intboolstring I did `git remote add origin https://github.com/me/myproj.git` and I get `fatal: remote origin already exists.`

Comment: Try running `git branch -a -vv` (and tell me the result)

Comment: Your github account is not authenticated by ssh key as suggested by your remote url .You are using password authentication.

Answer (score 1):

Did you add the local folder into the git environment so as to enable it to know where to push it?

normally you would:

- cd into folder
- type git init type git remote add origin
  https://github.com/user/repo.git

next steps depend on whether you have code you want to store in a fresh repo online or to pull a repo.

Pull is:

- git pull origin master

push would be:

- git add .
- git commit -m "Original Commit"
- git push origin master

Comment: I did `git clone https://github.com/me/myproj.git` instead of `git remote add origin https://github.com/user/repo.git`

Comment: Now if I do `git remote add origin https://github.com/me/myproj.git` I get `fatal: remote origin already exists.`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10904339/github-fatal-remote-origin-already-exists

Comment: git clone by default add remote to your app.You don't need to add it manually after clone

Answer (score 0):

git clone by default add remote to your app.You don't need to add it manually after clone

```
git remote add origin git_url
```

Here origin is just work as a alias for url. You can name it whatever you want.
This is used for mapping application to github.It works as a address.
By default through git clone this address is added to your application.
To check if remote is added to your application you can use

```
git remote -v
```

Also you can add multiple remote to single application ex. github and heroku both need different url to push code.
In this

```
git remote add origin git_url

git remote add heroku (heroku_url or git_url)
```

When we add heroku and git to application and run

```
git remote -v
```

It show two remote url 
Also If remote url starts with https refer to password authentication else    ssh authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your time. What I did wasn first I uninstalled everything.

Then

Create a new account in gitgub.com

Download and install the github for desktop

On github desktop logout and login again with the username/password that you used at github.com (see [here](https://help.github.com/desktop/guides/getting-started/authenticating-to-github/))

Go to github.com, to your accoun, copy your normal email (gmail) and paste it in github desktop to “configure git”, paste it over the “nonreply git mail”  (see [here](https://help.github.com/desktop/guides/getting-started/configuring-git-for-github-desktop/))

Open Git Shell, hit

`git config --global user.name "YOUR NAME"`

and

`git config --global user.email "YOUR EMAIL ADDRESS"`

for configing  username/email 
(see [here](https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git/))

Now works in Git Shell

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem, my advise is to type "git remote set-url origin https://github.com/username/reponame"  before "git push origin master"

Comment: Avoid link only answers. Try to include why you think the linked resource answers the question in addition to the link in case the page contents change over time or the page becomes unreachable in future.