# How to handle Git error "remote origin already exists"?

Tags: git

I'm have two git accounts. When I am trying to register a second remote

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:RiyaKapuria/testing.git 
git push -u origin master
```

During pushing to my repo I'm getting this error:

> fatal: remote origin already exists

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Github "fatal: remote origin already exists"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10904339/github-fatal-remote-origin-already-exists)

Comment: Can you please execute `git remote -v` in your local Git repo and share the output with us?

Comment: riya@RFL113:~/Desktop/test$ git remote -v
another_origin git@github.com:RiyaKapuria/testing.git (fetch)
another_origin git@github.com:RiyaKapuria/testing.git (push)
origin git@github.com:RiyaKapuria/testing.git (fetch)
origin git@github.com:RiyaKapuria/testing.git (push)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

replace origin by another name. because origin already exists.
Like

```
git remote add upstream git@github.com:RiyaKapuria/testing.git
```

Answer (score 6):

You already have a remote named `origin` (the one you cloned from). Just give the new remote a different name and you should be OK:

```
$ git remote add another_origin git@github.com:RiyaKapuria/testing.git
```

and then push to the `another_origin` by executing

```
git push -u another_origin master
```

Comment: Now i'm getting this error    $: git remote add another_origin git@github.com:RiyaKapuria/testing.git      $: command not found

Comment: @RiyaKapuria I use`$` in the common way to indicate a shell prompt. It's not part of the command

Comment: $ git push -u another_origin masterERROR: Permission to RiyaKapuria/testing.git denied to railsfactory-riya.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.