# Git_can't push locate update to remote branch successfully

Tags: git

```
 $git log
 commit e9b08e2b428f9dd58aa0b792ebeb29da4270dfab (HEAD -> master)

 $git remote -v
 origin  https://github.com/Shell_learning (fetch)
 origin  https://github.com/Shell_learning (push)

 $git branch -a
 * master

 $git push -u origin master
 remote: Not Found
 fatal: repository 'https://github.com/Shell_learning/' not found

 $git remote add origin https://github.com/ekoopgj/Shell_learning
 fatal: remote origin already exists.
 #It is really strange that the repository already exists ,but I can't push my local update to remote branch.
```

I have created a repository in my github like below:

[image: my github remote branch]

So , please tell me what's the issue.

Comment: That is not a valid GitHub URL.

Comment: [**This question is already answered here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10904450/7558125)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Github "fatal: remote origin already exists"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10904339/github-fatal-remote-origin-already-exists)

Answer (score 2):

The URL you're currently using for your `origin` remote is not correct. The format for a GitHub repository URL should follow https://github.com/username/repository.git

Once you have defined a remote, you can't change it by using `git remote add` - you have to use `git remote set-url`.

This script should update your `origin` to the correct URL.

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/ekoopgj/Shell_learning.git
```

Comment: Or, given that things are configured incorrectly, one might also choose to go back to a known state by removing the `origin` remote and then re-adding the configuration correctly

Answer (score 1):

you need to append `.git` to the repository address:

```
 git remote set-url origin https://github.com/ekoopgj/Shell_learning.git
```