# Repo not found fatal error while using git and unable to push to github

Tags: git, github, ssh, ssh-keygen

I've checked stackoverflow a lot trying to figure out why I could be receiving this error because I do have a repo on github for what I am trying to push to. I even regenerated my ssh key and added it to github. I also see:

```
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
```

and the repository exists.

When I try to add the repo remotely I see:

```
$ git remote add origin git@github.com:<username>/<reponame>.git
> fatal: remote origin already exists.

$ git push

fatal: The current branch master has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

git push --set-upstream origin master
```

Then I get the error

When I try

```
ssh -T git@github.com
```

I see the correct username

Not sure what else to try.

Comment: This link can help: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10904339/github-fatal-remote-origin-already-exists)

Comment: What does `git remote show origin` tell?

Comment: ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have already typed

```
$ git remote add origin git@github.com:<username>/<reponame>.git
```

you can not type it again, because origin is exist now.
And it will respond

> fatal: remote origin already exists.

but the address which link to origin may wrong.
Try to type

```
$ git remote remove origin
```

and type

```
$ git remote add origin git@github.com:<username>/<reponame>.git
```

again.

Then type

```
$ git push origin master
```

If both the address and SSH key are correct, it may work.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
git push origin master
```

read this documentation for more options with git push

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push