# Set git credentials inside a Azure yaml pipeline

Tags: git, azure, azure-pipelines

I'm writing an Azure YAML pipeline which have to do a 'git push' to repo so, I've written my git commands inside a CmdLine@2 task. Something like this :

```
            git checkout -b foo-branch-$(Build.BuildId)
            
            git add myGeneratedFile

            git commit -m "My commit message"

            git config user.email "$(GitUserName)@foo.com"
            git config user.name "$(GitUserName)"

            git push --set-upstream origin feature/foo-branch-$(Build.BuildId)
```

Obviously this code doesn't work as git credentials aren't set anywhere. How can specify that commands?

My idea is reading them from a parameter just like $(GitUserName) or from a git secret.

Is there any parameter that I can hide to avoid showing the value in the log and when the user type it?

Comment: I think you could add your variables in `release` section of the `pipelines` in Azure devops. So you create your YAML file in `pipeline` section and use that in `release` to define steps

Comment: I'm still working in it :)

Comment: @arturn. Feel free to let me know the result. Thank you

Comment: Hi @arturn. Is there any update about this issue? Feel free to let me know if the answer could solve this issue

Comment: According to [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56541458/azure-pipeline-doest-allow-to-git-push-throwing-genericcontribute-permission), and the message I've got in the log, I have to set the "contributor" permission to Project Collection Build service. But I can't see that option, so I'm already investigating the issue...

Comment: Hi @arturn. Please refer to my update. In Yaml pipeline, you don't need to select the option. You could add persistCredentials: true when you check out the current repo. Then it will work.

Answer (score 16):

Based on your latest commnet, the option **Allow scripts to access the OAuth token** only exists in classic editor.

In Yaml pipeline, you could use the following command:

```
- checkout: self
  persistCredentials: true
```

The `persistCredentials` will leave the OAuth token in the Git config after the initial fetch.

Here is the example:

```
steps:
- checkout: self
  persistCredentials: true

- script: |
   git config --global user.email "email"
   git config --global user.name "Kevin Lu"
   
   
   
   git checkout -b master
   
   git add .
   
   git commit -m "My commit message"
   
    git push origin HEAD:master
   
  displayName: 'Command Line Script'
```

For more detailed info, you could refer to [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema#checkout).

**Update2:**

To solve this permission issue, you need to grant the **Contributor** permission to the service account: `Projectname Build Service(OrganizationName)` in `Project Settings -> Repositories -> Target Repo -> Permission`.

[image]

**Update3:**

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to do the same thing without having to modify the origin? 
As pipeline can clone the repo, might I can set permissions to push, without the need PAT...

Comment: @arturn Of course. Please refer to my update.

Comment: My pipeline yaml already had the persisCredentials and the error was the same. I think the problem is related with pipeline's permissions, 
I've check out the permissions dialog, but I can't found anywhere to set the 'Contributor' permission.

Comment: @arturn. Get it. Please refer to my update2. You need to grant the repo Contributor permission to Projectname Build Service(OrganizationName) instead of Project Collection Build Service.

Comment: I can't see that option (see https://ibb.co/2F2v0V8)

Comment: This permission is not for Pipeline. The Contributor  permission is for azure repo in **Project Settings -> Repositories -> Target Repo -> Permission**.

Comment: @arturn Please refer to my update3. Since the git command is used to push changes to Azure Repo , so you need to set the permission for repo. And the service account name is **Projectname Build Service(OrganizationName)**

Comment: Hi @arturn. Is there any update about this ticket?

Comment: Thanks, setting the appropriate permissions as you told me in the last comment works. But now, I think the answer is a bit confusing... 
Only set 'persistCredentials' and set the right repo's permissions is need to get it working.

Comment: Hi @arturn. persistCredentials  will leave the OAuth token in the Git config after the initial fetch. So it will  inherit the token used by the initial checkout. So it will work. If the service account has enough permission to operate the repo, the git command will run successfully in Azure Pipeline.

Comment: Hi @arturn. If the answer could solve your issue, you may consider accepting it as answer. Thanks

Comment: Sure, but as we told the answer is a bit confusing as it contains an extra steps not really necessary, please edit it, and I'll mark as accepted.

Comment: Hi @arturn. i have removed unnecessary steps. Please check the answer. Thank you

Comment: Turns out the exact service account used by the pipeline differs from tenant to tenant. A reliable way of knowing which account to give permissions to would be to check the logs: `TF401027: You need the Git 'GenericContribute' permission to perform this action. Details: identity 'Build\my-service-account-guid', scope 'repository'` and then to search by that my-service-account-guid .

Answer (score 3):

Just as an update, in case anyone is encountering the problem I was having.
I followed the steps in Kevin Lu's answer, for a release pipeline, but just checking "Allow scripts to access OAuth token" (which is supossedly the UI equivalent of `persistCredentials: true`) was not enough.

After checking the box, and setting the right permissions for Project Collection Build Service, I modified my script in the pipeline step to clone the repo using the token specifically:
`git clone https://$(System.AccessToken)<rest of url to github repo>`