# Commit files into azure git repo using azure devops

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-pipelines, azure-git-deployment

how to commit files into azure git repo using build pipeline.

I am generating some files from my azure ci pipeline and I want to commit those files into the same repo which I used in my ci pipeline.

I have added the azure CLI task and added an inline command to commit code but it gives me the error and not working.

```
git add .
git commit -m "test commit"
git push -u origin Trunk
```

Comment: Have you followed these steps in the docs? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/git-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001511

Comment: Yes it gives me "Cannot prompt because user interactivity has been disabled" error.

Comment: Additionally, i add this url befor git add "git remote set-url origin https://username:gitpassword@repository url"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For classic Mode pipeline:

You could enable the `Allow scripts to access the OAuth token` option.

[image]

And grant the Repo **Contribute** permission for **Project Collection Build Service Accounts**.

[image]

Git command:

```
   git config --global user.email "email"
   git config --global user.name "Kevin Lu"

   git add .

   git commit -m "My commit message"

   git push origin master
```

For Yaml Pipeline:

You could set the `persistCredentials: true` in YAML sample.

And grant the Repo **Contribute** permission for **Build Service** .

[image]

Yaml Sample:

```
steps:
- checkout: self
  persistCredentials: true

- script: |
   git config --global user.email "email"
   git config --global user.name "Kevin Lu"
       
   git add .
   
   git commit -m "My commit message"
   
   git push origin master
   
  displayName: 'Command Line Script'
```

For more detailed info, you could refer to [this ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66470759/set-git-credentials-inside-a-azure-yaml-pipeline/66487131?noredirect=1#comment118203458_66487131).

Comment: before git add  set origin by giving this url"git remote set-url origin https://username:gitpassword@repository url"

Comment: for whatever reason, mine requires `git push origin HEAD:refs/heads/main` all other variations of HEAD,main,master etc failed

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that both `Project Collection Build Service Accounts` and `<repo> Build Service (<org>)` have `Allow` in `Contribute` section:

[image]

Asssuming you already made all steps [Run Git commands in a script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/git-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001511) you should be ready to go. Please notice that documentation says that you should set `Project Collection Build Service`, but it is also necessary to set `Project Collection Build Service Accounts`.

Answer (score 0):

FYI this can also be achieved using GitHub as-well, all that is required is the Service Connection running the pipeline has permission to commit to the GitHub repository, you can then run the following below:

```yaml
steps:
- checkout: self
  persistCredentials: true
  fetchDepth: 0
  
- bash: |
    echo "This Is Build $(Build.BuildId)" > "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/BuildNumber"
  displayName: Create File
  
- bash: |
    git config user.name "John Smith"
    git config user.email "John.Smith@example.com"
  
    git checkout main --
    git add --all
    git commit -m "Adding Build File"
    git push origin main
  displayName: Git Commit
```

Ref: https://jimferrari.com/2023/08/02/commit-files-to-github-during-azure-pipelines-run/