# Download Artifcats giving error in Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am creating this Release Pipeline and am getting error in Downloading Artifacts as

```
2021-03-09T10:54:21.2886849Z fatal: Cannot prompt because user interactivity has been disabled.
2021-03-09T10:54:21.2997811Z fatal: could not read Password for 'https://orgname@dev.azure.com/xyz/XYZ/_git/RepoName': terminal prompts disabled
```

What could be the issue, I am able to create release for other projects in the same environment. I checked the permission and there is no change.

Comment: Does this address your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64803872/azure-pipeline-cannot-prompt-because-terminal-prompts-have-been-disabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, my artifacts required "CheckOut files from LFS" to be selected and that fixed the issue.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the sharing, you could Accept it as an Answer, it could help other community members who get the same issues  Thanks. Have a nice day. :)