# Cannot remove remote origin

Tags: git

I'm running git 1.8.0 on OS X, and every new git repo seems to have a remote called "origin":

```
$ git init
$ git remote
origin
```

What's odd is that I can't remove it:

```
$ git remote remove origin
error: Could not remove config section 'remote.origin'
```

And therefore I can't add a new remote called `origin`. Why is this? What can I do to change it?

Comment: Sounds like you have a section in your global config file (`~/.gitconfig` - same place you set your name, e-mail, etc.) that starts with `[ remote "origin" ]`. Not sure how it got there, but if you remove that section the symptoms should go away.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You should be able to remove `origin` with

```
git remote rm origin
```

Not that you need to, you can just change the `origin` with `set-url`

```
git remote set-url origin "https://..."
```

Comment: Thanks, the `set-url` command does work. It'd be nice to get an explanation for why new git repos on my machine already have an `origin` with no corresponding `config` entry, though.

Comment: "origin" is hardcoded as the default push/pull target, see git-config entry for branch.<name>.remote.

Comment: @TrevorBurnham See also the `-o`/`--origin` options to [`git clone`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-clone.html) if you want to use a different name.

Answer (score 2):

Open the .git directory and edit the config file where it says [remote "origin"]

Comment: That's just the thing: `.git/config` contains no reference to `origin` or any other `remote`. That's why `git remote remove origin` doesn't work.

Comment: Amazing, best way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problems this way. First I opened up the `config` file using [vim](http://www.vim.org/) with the following command

```
$ vim .git/config
```

I modified my file to this below:

```
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = true
        bare = false
        logallrefupdates = true
        ignorecase = true
        precomposeunicode = false
[branch "master"]
[remote "origin"]
        url = git@192.168.200.79:xxx.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin_iOS/*
```

So now, when I give a command `git push` it understands, because by default it pushed to `origin` and it is set to my `origin_iOS` in my server.

You can check your origin config by `remote -v` command:

```
$ git remote -v
origin  git@192.168.200.79:xxxx.git (fetch)
origin  git@192.168.200.79:xxx.git (push)
```

If you don't have `'origin'`, you will have troubles with a usual `'git push'` as I did. I had to type `'git push origin_iOS master'`, because I had in my config `'origin_iOS'`

Answer (score 0):

Look in the global git config file
C:\Users\yourusername.gitconfig
or
/etc/.gitconfig

If [remote "origin"] is configured in the .gitconfig file, (or locally .git\config)
then the "$git remote rm origin" command will not work.