# Can't change git remote origin

Tags: git

Can someone explain why git remote origin cannot be changed from livepost.git to europeanexplorer.git? I tried following the directions, but documentation states that `error: Could not remove config section 'remote.origin'` means the file doesn't exist which clearly seems to not be the case here.

```
$ git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/harrisongill/livepost.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/harrisongill/livepost.git (push)
$ git remote rm origin
error: Could not remove config section 'remote.origin'
$ git remote set-url origin https://github.com/harrisongill/europeanexplorer.git
$ git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/harrisongill/livepost.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/harrisongill/livepost.git (push)
origin  https://github.com/harrisongill/europeanexplorer.git (push)
$ git remote rm origin
$ git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/harrisongill/livepost.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/harrisongill/livepost.git (push)
```

**EDIT:** Add git config

```
$git config --list
Harrisons-MacBook-Pro:European Explorer harrison$ git config --list
user.name=Harrison Gill
user.email=my email
remote.origin.url=https://github.com/harrisongill/livepost.git
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.precomposeunicode=true
```

Comment: That's unusual. Please post the `[remote "origin"]` section of your `.git/config`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All command line commands write strings into files in your `.git/` directory.
Remotes are configured conveniently inside `.git/config` file, and I think that's what [Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/354577/chris) was referring to.

So, if you do `vim .git/config` you should see something like this:

```
[core]
  repositoryformatversion = 0
  filemode = true
  bare = false
  logallrefupdates = true
  ignorecase = true
  precomposeunicode = false
[remote "origin"]
  url = git@github.com:harrisongill/livepost.git
  fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

and perhaps something else that's confusing to git in the `[remote "origin"]` section :P.

Why did it get messed up? I don't know. However just manually editing this file should set you straight :)

Get rid of the extra stuff and you should be good to go :)

Comment: Yep, just needed to delete what was after `[remote "origin"]` directly in the `.git/config` file. Thanks @apprenticeDev

Answer (score 5):

Original answer Jan 2014

As commented in "[Cannot remove remote `origin`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13572191/cannot-remove-remote-origin#comment18597979_13572287)", the error message `error: Could not remove config section 'remote.origin'` means there is no remote 'origin' in your Git config file.

At least not in your *local* config file.

I just tested adding a remote "origin" section in my *global* config file, and I got what you have:

```
C:\Users\VonC\prog\git\tests\21195717\t>git config --global --edit

C:\Users\VonC\prog\git\tests\21195717\t>git remote -v
origin  https://a.com/b (fetch)
origin  https://a.com/b (push)

C:\Users\VonC\prog\git\tests\21195717\t>git remote rm origin
error: Could not remove config section 'remote.origin'
```

Check your global config file:

```
git config --global --edit
```

---

Update February 2016

Git 2.8 will update that error message to "`no such remote`".

See [commit a31eeae](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a31eeae27f38246ba35000fa603d884cdd1a81ae), [commit cc8e538](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cc8e538d45e4260b27196c3238e6f15d64236523), [commit 674468b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/674468b3642abfff7c61d5ff95fffc43b87f70b7), [commit bc60f8a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bc60f8a77c6e676225810f33117abcf9117b1c1e) (16 Feb 2016) by [Thomas Gummerer (`tgummerer`)](https://github.com/tgummerer).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit ae2f255](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ae2f25542ffdd1919b33c8f274f8172e49d64dbf), 26 Feb 2016)</sup>

> ### remote: actually check if remote exits
>
> When converting the git remote command to a builtin in 211c89 ("Make
>   git-remote a builtin"), a few calls to check if a remote exists were
>   converted from:
>
> ```
>   if (!exists $remote->{$name}) {
>       [...]
> ```
>
> to:
>
> ```
>   remote = remote_get(argv[1]);
>   if (!remote)
>       [...]
> ```
>
> The new check is not quite correct, because `remote_get()` never returns
>   NULL if a name is given.
>   **This leaves us with the somewhat cryptic error message "`error: Could not remove config section 'remote.test'`", if we are trying to remove a remote that does not exist, or a similar error if we try to rename a remote.**
>
> Use the `remote_is_configured()` function to check whether the remote
>   actually exists, and die with a **more sensible error message ("`No such remote: $remotename`")** instead if it doesn't.