# Git commit combined two repositories into one

Tags: eclipse, git, github, eclipse-adt, github-for-mac

The initial commit for the project I am working on was on Jan 13, 2014. Somehow, the most recent commit added a 5 month old .gitignore file from a different project (which was not added three months ago) as well as nearly 500 commits from an entirely different github repository (everything before Jan 13, 2014). Can someone explain how this happened and whay should be done about it? I haven't worked on the older project in quite some time, however I may have cloned a more recent version via Github for Mac around the same time as the last commit to this repository.

Here is the repository in question: https://github.com/harrisongill/EuropeanExplorer/commits/master.

Any help on how I can fix this repository will be much appreciated. It should only have like 3 commits.

**EDIT**: It might have something to do with this: [Can't change git remote origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21195717/cant-change-git-remote-origin)

**EDIT 2**: It could be a problem with Eclipse. Eclipse has the other projects .gitignore file as well as .git directory in the project's working directory, however when I use terminal to view the same file the .gitignore (as well as .git directory), it doesn't appear. Is there a way to remove it in Eclipse? Delete is grayed out.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by completely deleting the android program and code from my computer. Then I cloned from Eclipse. Then I deleted the github repository. I re-set up the repository on github then followed these directions from the [EGit tutorial](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/#Pushing_to_upstream) to push it upstream to remote.

I'm not sure if it is the most elegant solution, but it worked. I still am not sure what happened, but if anyone has any idea or better suggestions in the future, please let me know.