# How can i remove unrelated git remotes from my project folder?

Tags: git

I'm seeing something odd with my git remote repos. When i list out the git remotes, i see some unrelated projects.

For some reason `git remote -v` is showing a bunch of old repos:

```
➜  WebApp git:(master) ✗ git remote -v
origin  git@github.com:garage/WebApp.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:garage/WebApp.git (push)
production  git@heroku.com:zoo-prod.git (fetch)
production  git@heroku.com:zoo-prod.git (push)
sandbox git@heroku.com:zoo-sandbox.git (fetch)
sandbox git@heroku.com:zoo-sandbox.git (push)
staging git@heroku.com:zoo-staging.git (fetch)
staging git@heroku.com:zoo-staging.git (push)
garage-prod https://git.heroku.com/garage-prod.git (fetch)
garage-prod https://git.heroku.com/garage-prod.git (push)
```

The entries for zoo-* are all from a different older project. I cannot remove them using the provided git commands:

```
➜  WebApp git:(master) ✗ git remote remove production

error: Could not remove config section 'remote.production'
➜  WebApp git:(master) ✗ git remote remove staging
error: Could not remove config section 'remote.staging'
```

How can i remove the unrelated remote repositories?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot remove remote origin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13572191/cannot-remove-remote-origin)

Comment: @JeffPuckettII `remove` has been available since 1.7.12.