# Git with no remote named origin

Tags: git

I have seen the related question [Cannot remove remote origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13572191)
 but it asks about adding a new origin (i.e. change the url of origin). However I would like to not have any remote named 'origin'.

If I have a remote named origin and run `git remote remove origin` it seem to replace that with an empty origin. `git remote -v` lists origin without url and it can't be removed.

Since git is distributed it would make sense to me to be able to have remote `A` and `B` none of them named origin. But a `git fetch --all` in this scenario will still complain that it can't fetch from that empty origin that I can't remove.

In summary: Is it possible to remove the origin remote completely?

Comment: try, `git remote rm origin`, may be both are same, but depenent on the version

Comment: @Sravan No that gives "No such remote: origin", but `git remote -v` still lists it.

Comment: restart the terminal and check once, whats the OS you are using

Comment: @Sravan Windows 7 and 10, git version 2.14.1. Restarting terminal does not help. Have you tried to reproduce?

Comment: Can you show the actual output of `git remote -v`? It may be possible that the name is slightly different from just “origin”.

Comment: @poke no it was exactly origin, but I got a working answer below now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run:

```
git config --show-origin --get-regexp ^remote
```

to see which `origin.*` entries are defined in which config files.  My guess is that you have defined `remote.origin` in your `$HOME/.gitconfig` file.

Comment: Thanks, this helped. I had an entry there to also fetch notes from origin which apparently makes it impossible to remove it: `[remote "origin"] fetch = +refs/notes/*:refs/notes/*`.