# Git project in Rstudio - restore changes from backup

Tags: r, git, rstudio

I have a repository named `abc` in git hub. I have a modified version(newer version) of the same repository in my Linux laptop as a backup folder- `abc_new`.

How do I get `abc_new` to link with `abc` in the server and commit the changes in `abc_new` to `abc`? I want to do it from RStudio

I tried to create a new project using the SSH url in my RStudio so i got a new folder `abc` created in laptop with all files from `abc` git server. Now how do I merge `abc_new` with `abc`? If I copy files from `abc_new` to `abc` and commit, it gets created as duplicate files in github server.

There are no forks and only 1 branch to my local for the project.

Tried the steps given in the link [https://happygitwithr.com/existing-github-last.html](http://steps) and got merge errors.

```
The last 2 steps `git remote add origin` and `git push` failed for me with  below errors `$ git remote add origin git@domain.com:path.git
fatal: remote origin already exists.
$ git push --set-upstream origin master
To git@domain.com:path.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@domain.com:path.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first merge the remote changes (e.g.,
hint: 'git pull') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
$`
```

Comment: Look at section17.5.4, look at your current remotes with git remote -v. Remove the origin remote using git remote rm origin. Then make sure you have the correct remote   git remote add origin yourremoterepo. Then git pull --set-upstream origin master. Then you should be able to push changes.

Comment: @JCran I get 2 origins when i do `git remote -v`.   With `(fetch)` and `(push)` respectively. And when given command `git remote rm` i get an error `error: Could not remove config section`. Did i mess up something?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13572191/cannot-remove-remote-origin is this helpful?

Answer (score 1):

Section 17.5.4: happygitwithr.com/existing-github-last.html. Could you add your github repo as a remote from abc_new using this method and push the changes.