# Push local git to new remote

Tags: git, github, git-remote

I have 2 git repositories set up, and I did a lot of coding in 1.  Someone else grabbed the code to make changes to the code, but never pushed them up.

The changes are now so large, I want to push it to an entirely new repository. I have their computer, and I tried to `git remote rm origin`. Then i tried `git remote add origin <url>`, but it gives the following error

> fatal: remote origin already exists.

Is there a way to push this to a new origin, and have it entirely forget about the first(like, not even remember it's a branch of the first)?

Comment: It is really difficult to understand your problem from your words.

Comment: Do you mind adding some details or making the problem statement clear ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove a remote, use `git remote remove <name>` you can see more details by `git help remote`

Also, I believe changing the meaning of `origin` is not a best practice, if you just need to temporarily push to a new remote, just add it with another name, such as: `git remote add <name> <url>`

When you add a new `remote` you can see it with `git remote` or `git remote -v` to see url details.

Then using `git push -u <your-new-remote>` would push your repo to `<your-new-remote>`

**EDIT:**

My fault, I didn't notice that `git remote rm <name>` is also usable since it did not appear in `git help remote`

Comment: @blunderboy Is it a new syntax or something? `git help remote` only gave me `git remote remove <name>`

Comment: Checkout this one http://stackoverflow.com/a/1221874/1310070 And also check your git version. May be earlier version of git had `git remove` But I never saw that.

Comment: Instead of `Edit` please update your answer. Quick Suggestion: Please try to male your point clear in short words. It looks like people won't prefer reading this. Just a quick thought..

Comment: @blunderboy It's not `git remove` it's `git remote remove` I think maybe you misread it to the `git rm` command? and also https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-remote.html did not say there is a `git remote rm`, but this can behave as `git remote remove`

Comment: Please try to use `git remote remove name`. It does not work my friend. http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes

Comment: May be you should check your git version as well. Latest version of git use `git remote rm`

Comment: @blunderboy my git version is `1.8.5.1` both `rm` and `remove` is documented in https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-remote.html

Comment: This led me on the right path, ty.  The command I needed was actually `git push --set-upstream <name> master`

Answer (score 1):

I am not clear with your problem, still giving it a try. You might not need to remove **origin**. Instead add a new one with some other name like **original**

```
git remote add original <url>
git push -u original <branch_name>
```

**Edit**
To view all the remotes use `git remote -v`. Check the remote list before adding a new remote.
It will tell you which remote_name is available and which is not.

**Edit2**

If you have already added a 'git origin' to your `.git configuration`.
You can **change the remote origin URL in your git config** with the following line:

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:{user}/{project}.git
```