# Deploying on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I have a problem that I've not encountered before.

A group of people has come together fast, to put a website together for an urgent public good cause.

I coded the app (in rails). I have created a heroku app with it and it is now published on a heroku free site. Someone else in the group bought the domain name and has made an account in heroku. We can't figure out how to link them.

When I try:

```
heroku git:remote -a ampuni
```

I get an error which says:

```
You do not have access to the app ampuni
```

When I try:

```
git remote add heroku git@heroku.com:ampuni.git
```

I get this error:

```
remote heroku already exists
```

Does anyone know how to link these two separate phases together? Thank you very much

Comment: refer this links, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221840/remote-origin-already-exists-on-git-push-to-new-repository
OR
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10904339/github-fatal-remote-origin-already-exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to access [Heroku Dashboard](https://dashboard.heroku.com/) from the new account who are owner of the app with domain configured. Follow Access tab and add your personal account as an collaborator. Then, you'll be able to make pushies to destination heroku repo.

Go to your local repo and add a new remote with different name using `git remote add heroku-upstream git@heroku.com:ampuni.git`.

And now, you can deploy your app using `git push heroku-upstream master`.

Answer (score 0):

I think on your system there is one heroku user credential is already exist, first you need to logout & remove that user credential along with ssh keys, then login with new account on system and then try your commands, it may work.