# How to reset git server association

Tags: git, github

I want to set my local repository to push to a new origin.
This is what I've tried:

```
~ git remote add origin https://my/git/origin.git
> fatal: remote origin already exists.
```

For your information:

```
~ git remote -v
> origin    https://my/git/origin.git (fetch)
> origin    https://my/git/origin.git (push)
```

Comment: what does output of `git remote -v` look like?

Comment: You've used the phrase "it doesn't work" a few times (in your title, in your question, and in a comment to the answer below). In general, this isn't helpful. Please make sure to include the *exact error messages* that you receive. We won't be able to help without them.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remote origin already exists on git push to new repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221840/remote-origin-already-exists-on-git-push-to-new-repository)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432764/change-the-uri-url-for-a-remote-git-repository

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Git servers for your project are saved as "remotes".
The default remote is usually called `origin`. You can have more than one, but all your remotes must have unique names.

The error you get is telling you that you already have a remote called `origin` configured. To know what remotes are configured for your local project, type [`git remote`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote) (or `git remote -v` for a more detailed view).

#### To remove your default remote, type

```
git remote rm origin
```

Then you will be able to add a new remote just as you were trying to, with

```
git remote add origin https://my/git/origin.git
```

However, **I advice adding a new remote** with a different name and then setting it as the default upstream. This way you could always come back and then, for example, [`git rebase origin master`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) to keep your repo in sync with the original source.

```
git remote add mynewremote
git push -u mynewremote master
```

Comment: How I can do a commit in an empty repository in this case

Comment: Have you tried the easy way, being `git commit` and then `git push`?

Comment: yes I have tried. I have cloned the repository in a empty directory in my local. after I done a commit and push. But doen´t work

Comment: the problem is that I am cloning the repository of a proper not the mine.