# Azure GitHub deployment failing with error "Remote 'external' already exists."

Tags: git, azure, github, azure-web-app-service, azure-deployment

I have a repository in GitHub that I've been using as source control for local development.

I just created a new Azure website and tried setting it up for continuous deployment from my GitHub repository. But each time I try and sync, I get an error that says Deployment Failed. If I look in the logs, all I see it

> Remote 'external' already exists.

Anybody know what this means and how I can fix it?

I don't think it's a problem with GitHub, I have several Azure applications that are syncing to GitHub just fine.

Comment: take a look at `.git/config`. There will be an entry `remote` named `external`. When syncing you somehow try to add that remote once again. What command sequence do you use for syncing?

Comment: A remote in git is, well, a preconfigured remote git repository (repository URL + settings specific for a given remote)

Comment: I checked the config file, there's no remote entry named external in there, this is all that's there: `[core]
 repositoryformatversion = 0
 filemode = false
 bare = false
 logallrefupdates = true
 symlinks = false
 ignorecase = true
 hideDotFiles = dotGitOnly
[remote "origin"]
 url = https://github.com/myname/mysite.git
 fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
 remote = origin
 merge = refs/heads/master`

Comment: I guess it would be better to put the config in the answer 'cause comments format isn't well suited for complex data structure. Anyway what's the syncing command sequence?

Comment: Can you share your web app name, either directly or [indirectly](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Reporting-your-site-name-without-posting-it-publicly)? This will help us investigate. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This error is not related to azure, this is just git telling you that you are trying to add a remote called "external" that it already exists in your configuration.

As I see it, you are trying to use github GUI. My advice will be that you should learn how to use the command line, many of the great features git has are only available through shell.

Second, if you just want to figure this out you can either remove the remote "external" and create it again:
[Remote origin already exists on 'git push' to a new repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221840/remote-origin-already-exists-on-git-push-to-a-new-repository)

Or you can just rename the remote:
[Github "fatal: remote origin already exists"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10904339/github-fatal-remote-origin-already-exists)

If you were to use the console, you would only have to do something like

```
git add --all .
git commit -m "My push to the server"
git push azure external
```

(I wrote "external" but it would have to be the branch you actually want)

More info here: 
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-publish-source-control/