# How to fix "fatal: remote origin already exists." on 'git remote add'?

Tags: git

I want to create a git repository on my USB stick. On the stick I created a bare git repository by using the command

```
git init --bare MyRepo
```

and in the repository on the laptop (Ubuntu 14.04) I issued the following commands

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m 'first commit'
git remote add origin /media/alexander/Stick/MyRepo
```

and got the error

```
fatal: remote origin already exists.
```

I successfully created a git repo on the stick just before without any error (using different directories of course). Now I get this error. The output of 'git status' is

```
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

So what is going wrong?

Comment: Make sure you didn't run `git init` in the wrong directory (in an already existing Git repo).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remote origin already exists on 'git push' to a new repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221840/remote-origin-already-exists-on-git-push-to-a-new-repository)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Remove the remote `origin` first, then add again with the path.

```
$ git remote rm origin
$ git remote add origin <repo-url>
```

**Another way:** Set the `origin's` url instead of adding.

```
$ git remote set-url origin <repo-url>
```

Comment: Yes, maybe that worked. But how did I get into this problem in first place?

Comment: I guess, `.git` folder already existed when you did `git init` command. Can you check the output of `git init` command? if output like **"Reinitialized existing Git ..."** then .git already existed and `origin` existed also.

Comment: Also, before doing this, it could be interesting to check `git remote -v` and `git remote show origin` to see what might be there.

Answer (score 0):

```
1. create new directory name similar to that created on github on your desktop
2. copy all the files and directory to the corresponding new directory
```

Commands:

```
git init
```

In case any error

```
git rm .git
```

Add all files to be pushed

```
git add .
```

Check if all pushed correctly

```
 git commit -m "Commit Done"

 git branch -M main

 git remote add origin https://github.com/ank247/cPeer.git
 git push -u origin main
```