# Why is my app not pushing to bitbucket? (Michael Hartl's tutorial chapter 3 section 3.1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, github, bitbucket

I am following Michael Hartl's tutorial (chapter 3 section 3.1 https://www.railstutorial.org/book/static_pages) using cloud 9 IDE and trying to push the sample_app to bitbucket.  When I type the following command into cloud 9 IDE:

> Since we’ll be using this sample app throughout the rest of the book,
>   it’s a good idea to create a new repository at Bitbucket and push it
>   up:
>
> $ git remote add origin git@bitbucket.org:/sample_app.git $
>   git push -u origin --all # pushes up the repo and its refs for the
>   first time

I get the following error

```
fatal: remote origin already exists.
```

(NOTE: I have changed username to my username).

Since I got the error I have tried several solutions including deleting everything from bitbucket fromt he previous exercises in the book.  so far i have followed the instructions to the letter, although I did accidentally close some of the tabs in the command line on cloud 9 and I don't know if this made any difference.  I also notice that nothing seems to have been created on git even though i did git init, git add -A and git commit. What have I missed. help is greatly appreciated so I can move on. Please let me know if there are any files I should add to an edit of this post. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remote origin already exists on 'git push' to a new repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221840/remote-origin-already-exists-on-git-push-to-a-new-repository)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> fatal: remote origin already exists.

The remote you're trying to add already exists. Run `git remote -v` and check in the ouput it gives to you, if is there, then skip the first command and pass the second one to push.

Comment: result of git remote -v as follows:   heroku  https://git.heroku.com/still-beyond-10331.git (fetch)
heroku  https://git.heroku.com/still-beyond-10331.git (push)
origin  git@bitbucket.org:owen358/sample_app.git (fetch)
origin  git@bitbucket.org:owen358/sample_app.git (push)

Comment: There's, your `origin` is `git@bitbucket.org:owen358/sample_app.git`, is it the same you're trying to add? if so, just use `git push`.