# How do you correct a bad git "remote add origin" command?

Tags: git, github

I am trying to add a file to my first github.com repository. I misspelled my username in the "git remote add origin" command. If I try and do it again correctly, it gives me an error:

```
fatal: remote origin already exists.
```

How to I clear the value so I can correct it? Or, how to I change what is there?

Comment: Does `git remote rm origin` and then re-adding it correctly help?

Comment: @meilke Yes, that worked.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remote origin already exists on 'git push' to a new repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221840/remote-origin-already-exists-on-git-push-to-a-new-repository)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to remove remote origin from git repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16330404/how-to-remove-remote-origin-from-git-repo)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use git remote set-url to update remote url

```
git remote set-url origin git://newurl
```

Comment: It worked but I don't understand the "git://newurl".  I did "git://https..." and got an error, so left off the "git:" and it worked.