# Can't push to Github repository for Azure project

Tags: git, powershell, azure-web-app-service

I'm attempting to finish an Azure web app tutorial. In the step "[Push to Azure from Git](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-get-started-nodejs)", I'm attempting to push to Github using, but getting error message

```
SivesA@ONE7-FAL138552 MINGW64 /c/2017/11 November/20112017/nodejs-docs-hello-world-master (master)
$ git remote add azure https://nodejsuser2@nodejswebappadamsives2.scm.azurewebsites.net/nodejswebappadamsives2.git
fatal: remote azure already exists.
```

no matter what URL I use.

I've been sure to inititalise and commit the project. I've also tried resolution through another [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221840/remote-origin-already-exists-on-git-push-to-a-new-repository), but seem to be hitting a brick wall. My remote properties are as follows:

```
SivesA@ONE7-FAL138552 MINGW64 /c/2017/11 November/20112017/nodejs-docs-hello-world-master (master)
$ git remote -v show
azure   https://adamsives@nodejswebapp.scm.azurewebsites.net/nodejswebapp.git (fetch)
azure   https://adamsives@nodejswebapp.scm.azurewebsites.net/nodejswebapp.git (push)
```

the Github repository is https://nodejsuser2@nodejswebappadamsives2.scm.azurewebsites.net/nodejswebappadamsives2.git

Comment: The error message is extremely straightforward. The remote already exists. Why are you trying to create it again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the remote with the name **azure** already exists on your system and that remote contains the url "**https://adamsives@nodejswebapp.scm.azurewebsites.net/nodejswebapp.git**".

As you have mentioned that you want your remote url as **"https://nodejsuser2@nodejswebappadamsives2.scm.azurewebsites.net/nodejswebappadamsives2.git"**. Therefore your need to do the following steps to update the url of the remote "**azure**":-

```
git remote set-url azure https://nodejsuser2@nodejswebappadamsives2.scm.azurewebsites.net/nodejswebappadamsives2.git
```

OR

You can add a new remote with new name like **"newazure"** with it's URL as you want. Follow the below command to add new:-

```
git remote add newazure https://nodejsuser2@nodejswebappadamsives2.scm.azurewebsites.net/nodejswebappadamsives2.git
```