# Push files from Azure to GitHub?

Tags: azure, github, azure-machine-learning-service

I have worked on a project in the Azure Machine Learning Studio. I wish to push the files from my storage account linked with the Machine Learning Service account.

I am new to the Azure Portal. I am mostly using the Jupyter Lab instance on Azure Machine Learning service.

How exactly can I push files from the folder I am currently working to my GitHub repository.

I could not find any documentation that will help me in Pushing Files From Azure ML to GitHub.

The following previously asked questions couldn't solve my issue:

[push-updates-from-azure-to-github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56855931/push-updates-from-azure-to-github) and [cant-push-to-github-repository-for-azure-project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47384274/cant-push-to-github-repository-for-azure-project).